# IOS 5 Storage Guidelines

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have developed iPhone app which contains a 80MB audio files and 20MB images inside the application bundle.I got a call from apple which says to update my app to follow the IOS5 storage guidelines otherwise my app will be remove from sale.
I have  read the IOS 5 storage guidelines which save data that in three different locations depending on the app requirement:-

1. Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the /Documents directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud.
2. Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in the /Library/Caches directory. Examples of files you should put in the Caches directory include database cache files and downloadable content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper, and map applications.
3. Data that is used only temporarily should be stored in the /tmp directory. Although these files are not backed up to iCloud, remember to delete those files when you are done with them so that they do not continue to consume space on the user’s device.
4. Use the "do not back up" attribute for specifying files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations. Use this attribute with data that can be recreated but needs to persist even in low storage situations for proper functioning of your app or because customers expect it to be available during offline use. This attribute works on marked files regardless of what directory they are in, including the Documents directory. These files will not be purged and will not be included in the user's iCloud or iTunes backup. Because these files do use on-device storage space, your app is responsible for monitoring and purging these files periodically.

So Since application bundle is not backup on icloud. So Do i need to move my all audio files from application bundle to the document directory or cache?

Expecting your favourbale reply.

Comment: Just wanted to add a link to [App Backup Best Practices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your file in private_Document folder under document directory with DO NOT BACKUP FLAG... if you will apply this flag to any of the folder then it will not backup.

```
(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL {
    NSLog(@"in add skipBackUpAtrribute method.......");
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your app IS the application bundle. Your app just doesn't exist without it. It would be useless to copy those files somewhere else because they would take up storage twice.

It is not backed up to iCloud because the app bundle can simply be downloaded again from the Appstore servers. So it would take up iCloud backup space without being useful. The application bundle is "public data" that is the same on all devices because it can't be changed.

I think apple talks about something else.

Comment: Apple *does* talk about something else: about files that your app creates at runtime (for example, by using `[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]`, `open`, or whatever).

Comment: @DarkDust I have made my appliction according to IOS 5  storage guidelines . Put everything inside the document folder and mark "DO not have attribute". But i have read apple other guidelines that you need to compile your app for all version of IOS that your app support. So what do i need to do changes in my code for erlier the 5.0.1 versions? can i put my all files inside the documnet folder or inside the cache?

Comment: If you adhere to the iOS 5 iCloud guidelines on where/how to store the documents then you're also fine for iOS < 5. Even setting the file attribute works on iOS < 5, it just doesn't have any effect. So in short: you don't need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to use `NSCachesDirectory`. I was publishing and update of one of my clients app and we store newspapers on Documents directory.

From iOS5 and ahead this folder is strictly reserved for user self created Documents. It's a mess cause you can't make a backup of important files. It's your responsibility to allow the download of the products, files or artifacts that your apps needs to work...

Comment: Thanks Pablo for your reply. I have change my code and include conditions like if device OD version is 5.0.1or above i am saving my data on NSDocumnentDirectory()  with "do not backup"and if version is < 5.0 then i am saving data in NSCacheDirectory.Am i doing write?

Comment: That correct. Once I changed the folder in the app Apple validates the update. If you found useful please check the answer as valid :) You may also want to implement a little function to move all the content saved into Documents to Cache ones.